# Laravel 5.5 Manually Validating CSRF Token

Tags: php, laravel, api, laravel-5.5

I am building an api driven Laravel 5.5 app. I want to use the publicly accessible api to process the UI driven requests as well.

My question is, in my api auth middleware, what is the best way to detect a UI driven requests (ajax requests) and allow it to pass through without trying to validate api auth credentials? (maybe try to validate csrf token?)

Comment: Are you using `Laravel Passport`?

Answer (score 2):

You can use a middleware to add additional checking for CSRF tokens although Laravel does that by default on web routes ([Doc](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/middleware#assigning-middleware-to-routes)).

for example add this Middleware for preventing accessing from anything but ajax:
run this command:

```
php artisan make:middleware AllowOnlyAjaxRequests
```

Then in the middleware file:

```
    namespace App\Http\Middleware;

    use Closure;

    class AllowOnlyAjaxRequests
    {
        /**
        * Handle an incoming request.
        *
        * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
        * @param  \Closure  $next
        * @return mixed
        */
        public function handle($request, Closure $next)
        {
            if(!$request->ajax()) {
                // Handle the non-ajax request
                return response('', 405);
            }

            return $next($request);
        }
    }
```

and then Add `'ajax' => \App\Http\Middleware\AllowOnlyAjaxRequests::class,` to your `routeMiddleware` array in `app/Http/Kernel.php`

([Middleware Docs](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/middleware#defining-middleware))

for detecting a request is sent via ajax you can use `$request->ajax()` code.
And if you want to exclude some URIs from validating CSRF (Do that with caution) you can do [this](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/csrf#csrf-excluding-uris).

Answer (score 0):

You can exclude specific routes from checking CSRF token in `VerifyCsrfToken` middleware.

After excluding it while validating request in your controller, you can validate CSRF token, if `$request->ajax()` returns `false`.

You can validate CSRF token by using `Session::token()` or `csrf_token()` function.

Answer (score 0):

Use this code in your controller:

```
function isValidCsrf(): bool
{
    return (Session::token() == request()->header('X-CSRF-TOKEN')) ||
           (Session::token() == request()->post('_token'));
}
```

Then you could use this code block in your controller:

```
if(request()->isMethod('POST') && isValidCsrf())
     /* Do something */
elseif(request()->isMethod('GET'))
     return view('....');
else
     abort(405,'only "GET, POST" methods are allowed");
```

And in your view you can use this in ajax request:

```
$.ajax({
   url: 'your url',
   type: 'POST',
   ...
   headers: {
      'X-CSRF-TOKEN': $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content') // for separate js files or scripts from your php code
      'X-CSRF-TOKEN': "{{ csrf_token() }}" //for inline blade files
   },/*☝️ OR */
   data: {
      '_token': $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content') //for separate js files or scripts from your php code
      '_token': "{{ csrf_token() }}" //for inline blade files
   }
   ...
});
```